Routing not functioning
In my App.js file I have created a router and it should have default page (Home).
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Navigation from "./Pages/Navigation";
import Home from './Pages/Home';
import Footer from './Pages/Footer';
import Projects from './Pages/Projects';
import Contact from './Pages/Contact';
import Policy from './Pages/Privacy';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navigation />
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" exact component={Home} />
          <Route path="/home" component={Home} />
          <Route path="/Projects" component={Projects} />
          <Route path="/Contact" component={Contact} />
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>

      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <br></br>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;

Home.js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import Carousel from 'react-bootstrap/Carousel';
import { FaPlaneDeparture } from "react-icons/fa";

function Home () {
  return (
    <section className="relative pb-2">
      <div className='w-full h-[700px] bg-gray-900/90 absolute'>
        <img className='w-full h-full object-cover mix-blend-overlay' src="https://megax.s3.amazonaws.com/1.png" alt="airpotimg" />
      </div>

      <div className='max-w-[1240px] mx-auto text-white relative'>
        <center>
          <div className='px-4 py-12 md:block hidden'>
            <div style={{ display: 'block', width: 800, padding: 30 }}>
              <Carousel>
                <Carousel.Item interval={4500}>
                  <img src="https://megax.s3.amazonaws.com/1.png" class="d-block w-100"></img>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item interval={2500}>
                  <img src="https://megax.s3.amazonaws.com/2.png" class="d-block w-100"></img>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item interval={2500}>
                  <img src="https://megax.s3.amazonaws.com/3.png" class="d-block w-100"></img>
                </Carousel.Item>
              </Carousel>
            </div>
            <h2 className='text-3xl pt-8 text-slate-300 uppercase text-center'></h2>
            <h3 className='py-4 text-3xl text-slate-300 text-center'>xxx</h3>
            <p className='py-4 text-3xl text-slate-300 text-center'>
              AWS
            </p>
          </div>
        </center>
      </div>
    </section>
  )
}  

export default Home;

Running my project with npm start shows this output:

As you see, the Home component is not shown as default route in my app. In fact, when I click on any other option in the navigation bar nothing happens! It looks like I am missing something with my router configuration or navigation method.
Navigation.js
/* eslint-disable jsx-a11y/anchor-is-valid */
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import { MenuIcon, XIcon } from '@heroicons/react/outline';
import { FaUserAlt, FaSignInAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';

function Navigation() {
  const [nav, setNav] = useState(false)
    
  const handleClick = () => setNav(!nav)

  const handleClose = () => {
    setNav(false);
  };

  return (
    // Navigation bar on large screen
    <div className='w-screen bg-gray-100 h-[70px] z-10 fixed drop-shadow-lg'>
      <div className='px-2 flex justify-between items-center w-full h-full'>
        <div className='flex items-center'>
          <h1 className='text-3xl font-bold text-black mr-4 sm:text-4xl'>Megax</h1>
          <ul className='hidden text-black md:flex'>
            <li className='cursor-pointer hover:bg-white hover:text-green-600 hover:rounded-lg'>
              <a href="/home">Home</a>
            </li>

            <li className='cursor-pointer relative group hover:bg-white hover:text-green-600 hover:rounded-lg'>
              <a href="/Projects">Projects</a>
            </li>
        
            <li className='cursor-pointer relative group hover:bg-white hover:text-green-600 hover:rounded-lg'>
              <a href="/Privacy">Privacy</a>
            </li>
        
            <li className='cursor-pointer relative group hover:bg-white hover:text-green-600 hover:rounded-lg'>
              <a href="/Contact">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className='hidden md:flex pr-4'>
          <a
            className="flex text-center cursor-pointer items-center mx-4 text-black hover:text-green-600"
            type="submit"
          >
            <FaSignInAlt className='lg:w-5 lg:h-5 mx-2' />
            <span className="text-sm font-medium">
              Login
            </span>
          </a>

          <a
            className="block cursor-pointer shrink-0 rounded-lg bg-white p-2.5 border border-gray-100 shadow-sm hover:bg-transparent hover:text-green-600 hover:border hover:border-green-600"
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Account</span>
            <FaUserAlt className='lg:w-5 lg:h-5' />
          </a>
        </div>

        <div className='md:hidden mr-4' onClick={handleClick}>
          {!nav
            ? <MenuIcon className='w-5 text-black' />
            : <div className='flex'>
                <a
                  className="flex text-center cursor-pointer items-center mx-4 text-black hover:text-green-600"
                  type="submit"
                >
                  <FaSignInAlt className='lg:w-5 lg:h-5 mx-2' />
                  <span className="text-sm font-medium">
                    Login
                  </span>
                </a>

                <a
                  className="block cursor-pointer shrink-0 rounded-lg bg-white mr-4 p-2.5 border border-gray-100 shadow-sm hover:bg-transparent hover:text-green-600 hover:border hover:border-green-600"
                >
                  <span className="sr-only">Account</span>
                  <FaUserAlt className='lg:w-5 lg:h-5' />
                </a>
                <XIcon className='w-5 text-black' /> 
              </div>
          }
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Navigation on small screens */}
      <ul className={!nav ? 'hidden' : 'absolute bg-zinc-200 w-full px-8'}>
        <li onClick={handleClose} className='border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full'>
          Home
        </li>

        <li onClick={handleClose} className='border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full'>
          Projects
        </li>

        <li onClick={handleClose} className='border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full'>
          Privacy
        </li>

        <li onClick={handleClose} className='border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full'>
          Contact
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Navigation

One thing I am not sure of is whether this is the reason for the failure of my page navigations through the navigation menus. I have not used Link object in my navigation component like the one below:
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

Instead I have just used  <a href="/home">Home</a> inside my navigation menu.

What version of React Router are you using? Is this v5?

@HamedJimoh       as per package.json: {
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.17.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.26.1",
"react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},

You're using react-router-dom v6 but the way you're rendering your component in the routes only works in v5. I'm going to reproduce the code on my end and fix your routes in convention with what obtains in v6.

You're using the routing convention of the React Router Dom version 5 but your installed version of React Router Dom is v6. That is why your navigation isn't working as it should.
Ideally, exact and component props of the Route components are only available in v5 and not in v6. So in essence, your routes aren't rendering the pages as intended. I have made adjustments to your App.js file where you're handling your routing.
   <div>
      <Navigation />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/">
          <Route index element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="home" element={<Home />} />
          <Route
            path="Projects"
            element={
              <div style={{ paddingTop: 150 }}>
                <p>Projects</p>
              </div>
            }
          />
          <Route
            path="Contact"
            element={
              <div style={{ paddingTop: 150 }}>
                <p>Contact</p>
              </div>
            }
          />
        </Route>
      </Routes>
    </div>

Also, I noticed you're using the anchor tag <a>...</a> in your Navigation component. While this is going to work on page navigation, this is going to cause page refresh on every navigation and that defeats the purpose of a single page application. I have now converted all your anchors into the <Link>...</Link>  component provided by React Router Dom.
import { useState } from "react";
import { MenuIcon, XIcon } from "@heroicons/react/outline";
import { FaUserAlt, FaSignInAlt } from "react-icons/fa";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Navigation() {
  const [nav, setNav] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setNav(!nav);

  const handleClose = () => {
    setNav(false);
  };

  return (
    // Navigation bar on large screen
    <div className="w-screen bg-gray-100 h-[70px] z-10 fixed drop-shadow-lg">
      <div className="px-2 flex justify-between items-center w-full h-full">
        <div className="flex items-center">
          <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold text-black mr-4 sm:text-4xl">
            Megax
          </h1>
          <ul className="hidden text-black md:flex">
            <li className="cursor-pointer hover:bg-white hover:text-green-600 hover:rounded-lg">
              <Link to="/home">Home</Link>
            </li>

            <li className="cursor-pointer relative group hover:bg-white hover:text-green-600 hover:rounded-lg">
              <Link to="/Projects">Projects</Link>
            </li>

            <li className="cursor-pointer relative group hover:bg-white hover:text-green-600 hover:rounded-lg">
              <Link to="/Privacy">Privacy</Link>
            </li>

            <li className="cursor-pointer relative group hover:bg-white hover:text-green-600 hover:rounded-lg">
              <Link to="/Contact">Contact</Link>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div className="hidden md:flex pr-4">
          <Link
            to="/login"
            className="flex text-center cursor-pointer items-center mx-4 text-black hover:text-green-600"
            type="submit"
          >
            <FaSignInAlt className="lg:w-5 lg:h-5 mx-2" />
            <span className="text-sm font-medium">Login</span>
          </Link>

          <Link
            to="/account"
            className="block cursor-pointer shrink-0 rounded-lg bg-white p-2.5 border border-gray-100 shadow-sm hover:bg-transparent hover:text-green-600 hover:border hover:border-green-600"
          >
            <span className="sr-only">Account</span>
            <FaUserAlt className="lg:w-5 lg:h-5" />
          </Link>
        </div>

        <div className="md:hidden mr-4" onClick={handleClick}>
          {!nav ? (
            <MenuIcon className="w-5 text-black" />
          ) : (
            <div className="flex">
              <Link
                to="/login"
                className="flex text-center cursor-pointer items-center mx-4 text-black hover:text-green-600"
                type="submit"
              >
                <FaSignInAlt className="lg:w-5 lg:h-5 mx-2" />
                <span className="text-sm font-medium">Login</span>
              </Link>

              <Link
                to="/account"
                className="block cursor-pointer shrink-0 rounded-lg bg-white mr-4 p-2.5 border border-gray-100 shadow-sm hover:bg-transparent hover:text-green-600 hover:border hover:border-green-600"
              >
                <span className="sr-only">Account</span>
                <FaUserAlt className="lg:w-5 lg:h-5" />
              </Link>
              <XIcon className="w-5 text-black" />
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>

      {/* Navigation on small screens */}
      <ul className={!nav ? "hidden" : "absolute bg-zinc-200 w-full px-8"}>
        <li onClick={handleClose} className="border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full">
          Home
        </li>

        <li onClick={handleClose} className="border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full">
          Projects
        </li>

        <li onClick={handleClose} className="border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full">
          Privacy
        </li>

        <li onClick={handleClose} className="border-b-2 border-zinc-300 w-full">
          Contact
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Navigation;

In addition, I have moved the BrowserRouter component that wraps around the Routes component to the index.js file (if you're using create-react-app) or main.js file (if you're using vite) and wraps it around the <App /> component.
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App.tsx";
import "./index.css";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </StrictMode>
);

Wrapping the BrowserRouter around the <App /> component which renders your Routes is necessary to prevent an error mentioned in this stackoverflow question:

Error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'basename' of 'React2.useContext(...)' as it is null"

